# External controls on Xmx limits for JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, dynamic-memory-allocation

Using a java based [program](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-hms/) that I am trying to get to run more efficiently. I'm not familiar with java, but the program documentation (pdf pg 15 [here](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-hms/documentation/HEC-HMS_Users_Manual_4.0.pdf)) suggests increasing the -Xmx upper memory limitation in the programs .config and .cmd files. I was able to up it to -Xmx1200M without problems on a previous machine but recently upgraded to a new machine (8GB vs 4, both windows 7 64bit and the same version of Java) but on the new system if I try to increase to over -Xmx834M I get a "Could not create the Java virtual machine" error on loading. Am I missing something obvious that could be causing this difference between systems?

There seem to be many resources on java memory allocation, but so far I've been unable to pick out my problem. There is plenty of memory available and I wouldn't think it was something within the program's java (like MaxPermSize) since it worked in the past. Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Edit:
VM Params from . config (produces error)

```
vmparam -Xms32M
vmparam -Xmx835M

vmparam -DMapPanel.NoVolatileImage=true
vmparam -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false

vmparam -Dpython.path=.

vmparam -Djava.library.path=.
```

Entire line from . cmd (produces error)

```
java\bin\java -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -DMapPanel.NoVolatileImage=true -Xms32M -Xmx835M %PY_OPTS% %JAVA_LIB_OPT% -classpath %JARS% %PROG% %ARGS%
```

Comment: `Could not create the Java virtual machine`, u usually get this error when there's something wrong with vm parameters. can you add your vm parameters ?

Comment: is it working if the value for -Xmx is less than 834M ? if that's the case may be you don't have enough free memory to allocate more than that, but on 8GB it's very unlikely unless you're running some resource intensive apps

Comment: At the default -Xmx800, to -Xmx834M the program runs without issue, with -Xmx835M or more I receive the error even when nothing else is running on the machine. I didn't author the program, any suggestions on what vm parameters might be causing the issue on one machine but not another like this? -Xms is at 32M

Comment: can you post the actual vm args that are giving you this error ? Exactly the way they're in your config and cmd files

Comment: I'm still actively interested in any suggestions/solutions to this problem.

Comment: Did you check your java version ?  Is it 32 bit or 64 bit ? Try `java -version` and see what it prints

Comment: 64 bit, Java 1.7.0_72-b14 is running on the two machines I described (the first which is able to run when set as high as 1200M despite having 4GB instead of 8GB the second which can't go above 834M). A third system also experiencing this limitation has java 1.7.0_45-b18.